# How can I extract the Id from a string in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm receiving the Id (number type) and a value (string type) from the backend and I'm passing it concatenated as a whole to another component:

```
const id = 12;
const value = "my_string_may_include_numbers_and_spaces";

const valueToSend = `${id} ${value}`

<MyComponent propString={valueToSend} />
```

Is there any way to take the prop and extract both values from inside `MyComponent` ?
id and value are separated by space but I could include anything in between, like * or % if that helps, I just haven't found a way to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why not pass in as two props?

Comment: [`value.split(" ")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: A reusable function is being used  to get those values and that would involve a bunch of changes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many people who do this value-concatenation thing use the pipe character `|`. In your case the value you'd send would be `12|my_string_may_include_numbers_and_spaces`.

This is convenient because

- pipe characters don't appear in many circumstances so they're a good delimiter.
- you can use `propertyString.split('|', 2)` and get an array of two strings.

You could also consider using the tab character. You type it `\t` in a Javascript string. This would look like so:

```
const delimiter = '\t'
const propertyString = [
              12, 
              "my_string_may_include_numbers_and_spaces"]
           .join(delimiter)
const array = propertyString.split(delimiter, 2)
```

The trouble with tab characters is that they're hard to see in console log and other debugging output.

Answer (score 1):

if I may I suggest a slightly different approach... in addition to to passing down the concatenated string, I would also create an object with two properties (id and value) and then pass that down as well to another prop.

```js
const id = 12;
const value = "my_string_may_include_numbers_and_spaces";

const valueToSend = `${id} ${value}`

<MyComponent propString={valueToSend} objProp={{id: id, value:value}}/>
```

or perhaps something like this:

```js
const newObj = {
  id: 12,
  value: "my_string_may_include_numbers_and_spaces",
  valueToSend: `${this.id} ${this.value}`
}

<MyComponent prop={newObj}/>
```

With the ladder option, you could then destructure if needed like this:

```js
const MyComponent = ({id, value, valueToSend})=>{
  doSomething(id);
  if( value ){
    return somethingCool( valueToSend );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use ( |,|| ) or any other special characters to create string
then send it to props
and whenever you want to use string,
try
string.split() method

```
const id = 12;
const value = "my_string_may_include_numbers_and_spaces";

const valueToSend = `${id} || ${value}`

const result = valueToSend.split('||')
```

Now using

```
result[0] //you can get your ID
result[1] //you can get your string
```

Hope all well !